# Spring data mongodb read only property keys are getting removed from database

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have annotated some keys in entity pojo with @ReadOnlyProperty because I don't want to set those field from working application because Those fields will be set/updated from different application.

```
@Document
public class SimpleClass{

    @Id
    @Field(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String id;
    
    // this key will be updated from current application
    private String key1;

    /// below key will be created/updated from different flow
    /// I don't want to create/update this data from current application
    /// I want this key for read purpose only
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private String key2;


    //SETTERS - GETTERS Ommited
}
```

I created mongo repository form that pojo.

```
public interface SimpleClassRepository extends MongoRepository<SimpleClass, String>{

}
```

I am trying to update the already read document by simpleClassRepository.save() method.
Database document is updating other fields but these @ReadOnlyProperty keys are getting removed from document.
I am using spring data mongodb 3.4.1.
Can anyone please suggest how to solve this problem

I tried to add @Version also in entity but still same result.

Answer (score 0):

The `save` method will override any existing document with the values present. If you need to preserve certain values please issue an update via the [template](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb-template-update) or [repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.update) API.